# Why doesn't my listCollectionView show new items added to the underlying list (in flex)?

Tags: apache-flex, listcollectionview

I have an (empty) ArrayCollection that I wrap with a ListCollectionView.
Then I add a series of items to the ArrayCollection, but these are not showing up in the view.

```
public var transactions : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
public var filteredTransactions : ListCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(transactions);
```

`transactions` contains 150 items, `filteredTransactions` contains none. I originally thought it was the filter I was applying, but even when I remove the filter, I still get no items in the filtered list.

Have I missed a step?
Do I need to add the items to the view as well as the underlying collection (this would seem to defeat the purpose of using a view though...)?

Comment: You do understand that ArrayCollection extends ListCollectionView, right? Any reason why you need to wrap an ArrayCollection inside ListCollectionView?

Comment: Because I have one collection that is used for all transactions (which I need to maintain separately) and then I need a view that shows how many match a certain criteria.

Comment: So what does a ListCollectionView provides that an ArrayCollection does not provide already? Do you want to clone the ArrayCollection ?

Comment: The array collection is just used to store a list of transactions (and having it be a collection rather than a straight array is purely for convenience). The view is to provide another (reduced) view of that same collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using addAll, addItem, or addItemAt to put items in the ArrayCollection, try that as a solution first.  Adding items directly to the Array that the ArrayCollection wraps will not dispatch CollectionEvents.

Also, try to use the ListCollectionView's refresh() method after setting its list property to the ArrayCollection.

If neither of these solutions work then please post additional code.

Comment: Thanks for that - I found somewhere else in the codebase that was referencing the original list and replacing it (grrr)... Now  replaced with addAll() which works perfectly.